A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action > Android resource linking failed
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action

Android resource linking failed

After updating flutter to 3.24, this problem arose again. It is related to the fact that now flutter checks the versions of compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion. Some packages either specify outdated versions or do not specify them at all.
As a solution, you need to update your packages to new versions. Also, if you have packages where these parameters are still not specified, you can add a script to your build.gradle between the subprojects instructions. It will look something like this:
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.application") ||
                project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.library")) {
            project.android {
                compileSdkVersion 34
                buildToolsVersion "34.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}


After updating flutter to 3.24, this problem arose again. It is related to the fact that now flutter checks the versions of compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion. Some packages either specify outdated versions or do not specify them at all.
As a solution, you need to update your packages to new versions. Also, if you have packages where these parameters are still not specified, you can add a script to your build.gradle between the subprojects instructions. It will look something like this:
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
    if (project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.application") ||
            project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.library")) {
        project.android {
            compileSdkVersion 34
            buildToolsVersion "34.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

